# Why am I not able to apply a class to the span element close to the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have several tr's which is dynamically displayed inside the tbody.

In each tr,
There is a checkbox and beside the checkbox a span. Now am trying to add a class to the span close to the checkbox on click.

I have spent couple of days but can't get the exact thing I went. The closest I did was applying q class to all the spans.

I have searched here also, yet to find the solution. This is the html.

```
<table id="course">
<thead class="thead">
<tr>Course</TR>
<tr>description</tr>
<tr>units</tr>
<tbody id="courses">

<!-- this is where the tr's will be displayed -->

<!--example-->

<!--Row 1-->
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox"><span class="button is-link">MATHS</span></td>
<td>Elementary Maths</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>

<!--Row 2-->
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox"><span class="button is-link">SCIENCE</span></td>
<td>Elementary Bla Bla</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

This is the last code I tried to use.

```
$("#courses").on('change','.checkbox',function (){
$(this).closest("thead").find("span").removeClass("is-link").addClass("is-success");
});
```

Also tried this below, and it worked but it affected both spans.

```
$("#courses").on('change','.checkbox',function (){
$("#courses").find("span").removeClass("is-link").addClass("is-success");
});
```

I changed it to this. It's not working too

```
$("#courses").on('change','.checkbox',function (){
$(this). closest ("thead").find("span").removeClass("is-link").addClass("is-success");
});
```

These are few of what I have tried to no avail!!

Thanks for your answers in adv!!

All the jQuery is inside $(document).ready(function (){. Juss omitted it here

Comment: Your `<thead>` doesn’t contain any `<span>`s, so I’m not sure why you’re trying `.closest("thead").find("span")`, instead of, say, `.closest("td").find("span")`. Also, it’s not closed with `</thead>`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues here:

- The checkbox `input` has no `.checkbox` class. You need to either add the class or use the `:checkbox` selector instead.
- The `table` HTML is malformed. The `<thead>` element needs to be closed, the `tbody` should be a sibling of the `thead` (and not a child), and the content in the `thead` row should be in `td` or `th` cells.
- The DOM traversal logic is flawed, partially due to the malformed HTML.

To do what you require you need to just get the `closest('td')` and `find()` the target `span` from there. Also note that in this case you can use `toggleClass()` instead of separate `addClass()`/`removeClass()` calls.

With those issues corrected, the code would look something like this:

```js
$("#courses").on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
  $(this).closest('td').find("span").toggleClass("is-link is-success");
});
```

```css
.is-link { color: #00C; }
.is-success { color: #0C0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="course">
  <thead class="thead">
    <tr>
      <td>Course</td>
      <td>description</td>
      <td>units</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="courses">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"><span class="button is-link">MATHS</span></td>
      <td>Elementary Maths</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"><span class="button is-link">SCIENCE</span></td>
      <td>Elementary Bla Bla</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks to you all!!  I made couple of mistakes typing what I have here on the table. This solved it......................"To do what you require you need to just get the closest('td') and find() the target span from there. "

Comment: No problem, glad to help